# When using Map, CSS does not get applied

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The text I want to get rendered is rendered, but css is not applied. The css works perfectly when used on a item that is not mapped. On the app render method, the css gets applied, but on the message rendered, the CSS does not get applied for some reason.

I suspect that this is because of some technical issues to do with the list

```
const boyDivStyle = {
  backgroundColor: "blue",
  borderRadius: "25px",
  padding: "20px",
  width: 1*20 + "px",
}

class App extends Component {

  
  render() {
    return(
      <>
        <p style = {boyDivStyle}>random</p> 
        <AddHTMLTag/>
        
      </>
    )
  }
}

class MessageRenderer extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return(
      <>

        {this.state.listOfMessages.map(Message => (
          <p style = {boyDivStyle}>
             {Message}
          </p>
        ))}
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Quentin, sure I will post more

Answer (score 0):

```
const boyDivStyle = {
  backgroundColor: "blue",
  borderRadius: "25px",
  padding: "20px",
  width: 1*20 + "px",
}

class App extends Component {

  
  render() {
    return(
      <>
        <p style = {boyDivStyle}>random</p> 
        <AddHTMLTag/>
        
      </>
    )
  }
}

class MessageRenderer extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return(
      <>
        {this.state.listOfMessages.map((Message) => {
                return (<p style = {boyDivStyle}>{Message}</p>)
        }
        )}
      </>
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: Well. That's some code. It isn't really an answer though. It reads like a game of spot-the-difference. Please explain precisely what you changed and why it should solve the problem.

Comment: If I run that through `diff` it looks like you've added the (completely) optional parenthesis around the `map` callback's argument and replaced the expression format arrow function with a curly brackets arrow function and an explicit return while deleting a couple of new lines. I can't see how that could possibly help. It's just moving the deckchairs around on the Titanic.

Comment: Hello, for me this still doesn't work. thanks for answering anyway